# Special Character Meanings Defined

Tags: python, character-codes

In Python's module named `string`, there is a line that says `whitespace = ' \t\n\r\v\f'`.

- `' '` is a space character.
- `'\t'` is a tab character.
- `'\n'` is a newline character.
- `'\r'` is a carriage-return character.

---

- `'\v'` maps to `'\x0b'` (11). What does it mean and how might it be typed on a keyboard (any OS)?
- `'\f'` maps to `'\x0c'` (12). What does it mean and how might it be typed on a keyboard (any OS)?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\v` is a vertical tab. It was used in line printers to advance about 6 lines or so. It can be typed in *nix by pressing Ctrl-V Ctrl-K.

`\f` is a formfeed. It was used in line printers to advance to the next page. It can be typed in *nix by pressing Ctrl-V Ctrl-L.

Answer (score 2):

`\v` is a [vertical tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key)

`\f` is a [formfeed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break)

See: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII):

> 12 (form feed, \f, ^L), to cause a
>   printer to eject paper to the top of
>   the next page, or a video terminal to
>   clear the screen.

`^L` means Control-L on most keyboards and OSes.

`\v`, code 11 (typeable as `^K`) is essentially obsolete, while `^L` is still occasionally used (e.g in vi to "refresh/repaint the screen" rather than just "clearing" it as in the original meaning).